# comparing strings in c# which calls C dll

Tags: c#, c, string, dll, marshalling

(Day 2 of learning c#) I am passing a buffer to a C dll from C#. The C func copies the string "text" into the buffer.  Back in the C# code, I compare "text" with what's in the buffer and it doesn't compare equal.  What am I missing?

```
    extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )      
    int  cFunction(char *plotInfo, int bufferSize) 
    {
        strcpy(plotInfo, "text");
        return(0);
    }
```

c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("mcDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
                                                      CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int cFunction(StringBuilder theString, int bufSize);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(55);
            int result = cFunction(s, 55);
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            string zz = "text";
            if (s.Equals(zz))
                Console.WriteLine( "strings compare equal");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("not equal");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s` is a `StringBuilder`, while `zz` is a `string`.

Try comparing

```
s.ToString().Equals(zz);
```

Generally, `Equals()` performs a reference comparison for reference types.  Some classes (such as String) override `Equals()` to allow for strings that contain the same characters to be considered equal (though for performance purposes, I believe the actual implementation first checks for reference equality, then compares the contents of each string).

Your current code is calling the .Equals() method of `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in comparison of a `StringBuilder` to a `string`  Comparing any `StringBuilder` to a `string` will always return `false`.

The [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class has two Equals overloads:

1. [Equals(object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) which is inherited from `object` and performs a reference comparison.
2. [Equals(StringBuilder)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccth01t4.aspx) which compares two `StringBuilders` based on the string they contain.

You are calling overload 1, so it is not comparing the contents.

Call `.ToString()` on `s` to get the string that it contains and then call `Equals` on that to get a string comparison.